# Create a list of months based posts

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query, date

Hey WordPress Development,

Currently, I have to create a list of months based on the date query of custom posts I have for the current year. I am probably not saying this right so hopefully my format example below is some help.

So if I have 30 posts for July and 15 posts for August I want to create two links that read like this...

```
<a href="/data/?m=Aug">August</a>
<a href="/data/?m=Jul">July</a>
```

I don't think I could use a *wp_archives* because I need to output this format. Reason being is I'm doing a some ajax functions on the page and it's easier to just use *$_GET* variable.

Thank you in advance.

*Edit*
I guess a better way of asking is... How do I display the most recent post from each month?

Comment: What are your inputs? Where do months come from?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but inputs. But I'm trying to use the date of the posts for the month.

Comment: Why does your example have July and August? Where do you have 30/15 example posts and how?

Comment: OH gotcha, July and August are just the two months worth of data I have populated. Basically, I'm using posts because a client will be adjusting a data points for each day of the month. I then want to take those posts and make a query to make a link to each month. So right now I wrote a wp_query that lists all the posts but instead of I want it to list the months with posts. Does that make sense? It's really hard for me to explain technical things sometimes.

Comment: I guess a better way of asking is... How do I display the most recent post from each month?

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
<a href="/2016/8/?post_type=post">August</a>
<a href="/2016/7/?post_type=post">July</a>
```